# Creating a post similar to LinkedIn form w/ Post Preview Mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, linkedin-api, next.js13

can anyone share their insights on how to implement the `Post Form` similar to `LinkedIn` but only its behavior not the ui exactly. Does it uses rich text editor? If so, can u recommend a package that I can use? Also, I am trying implement it with `Post Preview Mode` before posting.

The app that I am implementing is similar to `Taplio` and `Seenly`. Hope anybody can help.

Comment: What do you mean by Post Form?

Comment: the create post modal in linkedin

Answer (score -1):

You should store on localdb. After, You can get data and implement on second preview div. You might use angular.js for solution of this problem. You can look at on GıtHub.

Comment: do u mean local storage? and is it possible to use it with nextjs than angular.js?

Comment: can u also share the github ur referring to?